# No Private key found in keystore in SOAPUI tool

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

In SOAPUI tool, i am trying to consume SOAP WebService by passing Keystore and truststore file. While doing so, i am getting the below error "No Private key found in Keystore.jks file"

Comment: what is output of keytool -list -v -keystore Keystore.jks